# Exercício de python

Tags: python

No codeacademy, estou tendo o erro com o seguinte código:

```
# Tenha certeza que the_flying_circus() retorna True
def the_flying_circus():
    if  5==5 :    # Comece seu codigo aqui!
    return True
        # Nao esqueca de recuar
        # o codigo dentro deste bloco!
    elif 5!=5 or 6>=4 :
    return False
    else: 
    return False
        # Continue aqui.
        # Voce vai querer adicionar tambem a declarao else!
```

Erro:

> Seus recuos parecem um pouco estranhos. Leia a Dica se precisar de
>   ajuda!

Comment: Alguém ai me ajuda??

Comment: Essa é a coisa que mais gosto em Pyhton. Obriga o cara ser organizado :) pena que ainda deixa fazer código tosco, redundante :( O CodeAcademy ensina isto? Bom saber para eu não indicar.

Answer (score 7):

A indentação em `Python` deve ser respeitada para que o código seja executado em bloco perfeitamente.

Basta adicionar um `tab` ou `4 espaços`[[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119562/tabs-versus-spaces-in-python-programming) nas linhas que executam dentro das estruturas condicionais:

```
def the_flying_circus():
    if  5==5:
        return True //identar
    elif 5!=5 or 6>=4:
        return False //identar
    else: 
        return False //identar

print the_flying_circus() //chamar função
```

Testei esse código no próprio `codeacademy` e deu certo. Pode testar no [pythonfiddle](http://pythonfiddle.com/) também.

A indentação é uma característica predominante na linguagem `Python`.

Enquanto que os blocos de código são delimitados explicitamente em `C`, `Java` e `PHP` por chaves, em `Pascal` e `Fortran` por palavras-chave como `then` e `endif`, em `Python` blocos são delimitados por espaços ou tabulações formando uma indentação visual, <s>não existem símbolos</s>(na verdade, os símbolos, são as próprias tabulações, ou espaços) que indiquem quando o código de uma determinada função inicia, ou termina.

Por esse motivo `python` requer uma indentação padronizada. Em outras linguagens, como `C/C++` ou `JavaScript`, a indentação não é necessária devido aos delimitadores de blocos, sendo utilizada somente para melhor visualização.

Comment: não recomende más práticas, sugira usar 4 espacos e não tab para identação

Comment: @tovmeod existe uma discussão, mesmo que antiga, sobre esse assunto aqui no SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/119562/tabs-versus-spaces-in-python-programming, outro link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/120926/why-does-python-pep-8-strongly-recommend-spaces-over-tabs-for-indentation
Apesar dos pontos acrescentados, não acredito que seja ma pratica, mas sim questão de gosto de cada um, acredito que nesse caso a questão é o AP entender que os recuos representam blocos de código, por isso devem ser respeitados

Comment: Goste ou nao, este e o padrao adotado pela comunidade python, e errado ensinar a aluguem aprendendo o jeito de fazer as coisas diferentesdo que >90% faz